# How can I make more space between node and edge in Latex Tree Diagram?

Tags: latex

I want "Child" at the left to fit in better like the rest and I want more space at the right side between the last nodes and the calculations P(x) = 1/2

[image: Make child look better (move entire thing right) , and make space between P(xyz) and the last nodes]

this is the code:

```
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

%document already started 

% Set the overall layout of the tree
\tikzstyle{level 1}=[level distance=3cm, sibling distance=2cm]
\tikzstyle{level 2}=[level distance=3cm, sibling distance=1cm]

% Define styles for bags and leafs
\tikzstyle{bag} = [text width=1em, text centered]
\tikzstyle{end} = [circle, minimum width=3pt,fill, inner sep=0pt]

% The sloped option gives rotated edge labels. Personally
% I find sloped labels a bit difficult to read. Remove the sloped options
% to get horizontal labels. 
\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=right]
\node[bag] {Child}
    child {
        node[bag] {G}        
            child {
                node[end, label=right:
                    {G     $P(G\cap G)=\frac{1}{2}$}] {}
                edge from parent
                node[below] {0.5}
            }
            child {
                node[end, label=right:
                    {B  $P(G\cap B)=\frac{1}{2}$}] {}
                edge from parent
                node[above] {$0.5$}
            }
            edge from parent 
            node[below] {$0.5$}
    }
    child {
        node[bag] {B}        
        child {
                node[end, label=right:
                    {G    $P(B\cap G)=\frac{1}{2}$}] {}
                edge from parent
                node[below] {$0.5$}
            }
            child {
                node[end, label=right:
                    {B   $P(B\cap B)=\frac{1}{2}$}] {}
                edge from parent
                node[above] {$0.5$}
            }
        edge from parent         
            node[above] {$0.5$}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

%end of document
```

I don't know hat I can do. I have tried to change the width which is 1em right now. But if I increase it the diagram gets even more out of shape and if I decrease it it completely covers "Child"

I have tried to make more spaces behind the last event  (before the P(blabla) thing). But that didn't chnage anything.

Answer (score 0):

- repetitive spaces in latex are treated like a single space. If you'd like to manually increase the space, you could e.g. use `\qquad`
- to avoid your `Child` node from colliding with the lines, you can increase its text width. This will move it a bit further away from the lines
- don't use `\tikzstyle`, this macro is obsolete.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}

% Set the overall layout of the tree
\tikzset{level 1/.style={level distance=3cm, sibling distance=2cm}}
\tikzset{level 2/.style={level distance=3cm, sibling distance=1cm}}

% Define styles for bags and leafs
\tikzset{bag/.style={text width=1em, text centered}}
\tikzset{end/.style={circle, minimum width=3pt,fill, inner sep=0pt}}

% The sloped option gives rotated edge labels. Personally
% I find sloped labels a bit difficult to read. Remove the sloped options
% to get horizontal labels. 
\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=right]
\node[bag,minimum width=2cm] {Child}
    child {
        node[bag] {G}        
            child {
                node[end, label=right:
                    {G\qquad$P(G\cap G)=\frac{1}{2}$}] {}
                edge from parent
                node[below] {0.5}
            }
            child {
                node[end, label=right:
                    {B\qquad  $P(G\cap B)=\frac{1}{2}$}] {}
                edge from parent
                node[above] {$0.5$}
            }
            edge from parent 
            node[below] {$0.5$}
    }
    child {
        node[bag] {B}        
        child {
                node[end, label=right:
                    {G\qquad    $P(B\cap G)=\frac{1}{2}$}] {}
                edge from parent
                node[below] {$0.5$}
            }
            child {
                node[end, label=right:
                    {B\qquad   $P(B\cap B)=\frac{1}{2}$}] {}
                edge from parent
                node[above] {$0.5$}
            }
        edge from parent         
            node[above] {$0.5$}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]